# Proving that a set of functions is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In order to proof that a set A is a subspace of a Vector space V we'd need to prove the following:

- Enclosure under addition and scalar multiplication
- The presence of the 0 vector

And I've done decent when I had to prove "easy" or "determined" sets A.

Now this time I need to prove that F and G are subspaces of V where:

F = {f ∈ V : f(−x) = −f(x) for every x ∈R} (every odd function)
G = {f ∈ V : f(−x) = f(x)  for every x ∈R} (every even function)

How can I prove the above stated question with sets liek F and G which are just functions?

Thanks!

Edit: V is the "Vector Space of the real-valued functions over R

Comment: Which vector space is $V$ in this context?  The function space of all continuous functions over the real numbers?  The function space of polynomials?

Comment: Suppose that $f,g\in F$.  That means that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $g(-x)=-g(x)$ for each $x$.  Now, let's check that $F$ is closed under addition.  We ask, if we know that $f$ and $g$ are in $F$, does it follow that $(f+g)$ must also be in $F$?  To check that, we ask, is $(f+g)(-x)=-(f+g)(x)$?  Recall that $(f+g)(-x)=f(-x)+g(-x)$ and use what we already know about $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry I forgot to specify that, I edited the post accordingly

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok so from my understanding here I see that (f+g)(x) = f(-x) + g(-x) and thus (f+g)(-x), and I'd say ok for the enclosure under addition. But how would it look like with the scalar?  (alpha f)(x)...(alpha f)(-x)?

Comment: @ShadeReogen I think it might be helpful to look at what makes your $V$ a vector space in the first place; how vector addition and scalar multiplication are defined on it, and what the zero vector is. Once you're clear about that, I think proving that odd/even functions are subspaces will be much easier.

Comment: The set-theory tag does not fit this question. Please don't add it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $V=F(-∞,∞)$ i.e set of all real valued functions over $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider given set $F=\{f(x)\in V: f(-x)=-f(x)\}$.

Clearly if $f,g\in F$ then $(f+g)(-x)=f(-x)+g(-x)=-f(x)-g(x)=-(f(x)+g(x))$

So that $F$ is closed with respect to addition. Now for $k\in \mathbb{R}$ consider, $(kf)(-x)=k•f(-x)=-k•f(x)$

Hence $F$ is closed with respect to scalar multiplication.

So that $F$ is subspace of $V=F(-∞,∞)$

Now can you do same for $G$?

Comment: Many thanks! Now that I have it clear for this type pf sets I think I can do it for another one!

Comment: @ShadeReogen i was happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to see from where this question arise:

We can write any function as a sum of an even and an odd function as below:
$$f(x) = \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2} + \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$$
That the first term is even and second one is odd as desired. So the space of all functions can produce by these two subspaces. Therefore they are a basis for this space.